# Breaking a long equation up into two lines in R Markdown

Tags: r

I am using R Markdown using the `texevier` package

I have a long equation which I would like to seperate into two lines by seperating with a linebreak operator "\\". Here is the code chunk that I'm trying to run

```
\begin{equation}
l = -0.5 \sum_{t=1}^{T}[n log(2\pi) + log(\mid H_t \mid) + \varepsilon_t^{'} H_t \varepsilon_t] \\ = -0.5 \sum_{t=1}^{T}[n log(2\pi) + log(\mid D_t R_t D_t \mid) + \upsilon_t^{'}D_t^{-1}R_t^{-1}D_t^{-1}\upsilon_t]
\label{eq5}
\end{equation}
```

However, it seems that this does not make the contents after the seperator start on a seperate line. Does anyone have advice on how I should go about doing this?

Comment: Shot in the dark. Try `\\\` (two, or more, backslashes)?

Comment: I have done that in my code, however that doesnt seem to work

Comment: Arh, I think you might need to use `\begin{gather*} ... \end{gather*}` or  `\begin{align*} ... \end{align*}` instead of the `equation` environment in latex.